# Flutter vs React Native. Which framework is more native in terms of style out of the box?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, react-native

I am trying to find out which framework, Flutter or React Native, is more self-adaptive in terms of native style per platform ( e.g on Android you have checkbox, on iOS a switch ). In another words, in which framework you have to differentiate manually less  between 2 platforms, for example `isAndroid ? checkbox : switch`. After doing some research it seems that React-Native is **more self-adaptive than Flutter**, but also **React Native has less pre-built components**. So you have to build more yourself. Flutter, on the over hand, **has more pre-built components ( widgets )**, but **is not self-adaptive at all** as it heavily embraces material design ( Android style ). So the developer has to specifically tell Flutter " okay, here differentiate between iOS and Android ".

However, I am unsure about the above statements as I have made them myself by filtering out the information on the web. Therefore, I would like to get your opinion. Which framework is more native in terms of style out of the box without a need to differentiate between the platform manually?

P.S For me there is no difference wether an exact copy of an element is drawn pixel-by-pixel or it's an actual UI-element received via system-call as long as it looks the same.

Comment: Flutter has its own rendering engine which controls each and every pixel it renders on the screen while react native relies on system calls, that is native ui elements. So yeah, the answer to your question is React Native

Comment: @RituparnaWarwatkar that is not exactly what I asked. I am not interested in how the UI elements are delivered to the user, but how self-adaptive is the design based on the platform. Be it a drawn pixel-by-pixel version which looks exactly like native UI element or an actual UI element received via system-call.

Comment: In that case too, i feel the answer would not change. Suppose you are building flutter app, to embrace the platform differences you need to explicitly check and then use a desired widget. While in a react native app, you need not explicitly check and just use a react element and rest everything is done by the system. if it is on android, it would display a material button, if on iOS, it would display a cupertino button

Comment: @RituparnaWarwatkar I see your point, thank you! Do you think the trade-off of less reach pre-built components library in React Native comparing to Flutter is worth it due to the fact that those available pre-built components are automatically converted for corresponding design? In another words, the selection of available components is decent enough so that the developer will not have too much overhead of building custom once.

Comment: I really am not well qualified to make any comment about this exact stuff you asked just now. Sorry. I'll copy my comments as answers, please accept and upvote. Thank you

Comment: @RituparnaWarwatkar Okay, sure. Just was wondering if you know that as well. You gave a full answer to my question, so thank you :).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Flutter has its own rendering engine which controls each and every pixel it renders on the screen while react native relies on system calls, that is native ui elements. So yeah, the answer to your question is React Native

`Question:-` "But how self-adaptive is the design based on the platform. Be it a drawn pixel-by-pixel version which looks exactly like native UI element or an actual UI element received via system-call."

In that case too, i feel the answer would not change. Suppose you are building flutter app, to embrace the platform differences you need to explicitly check and then use a desired widget. While in a react native app, you need not explicitly check and just use a react element and rest everything is done by the system. if it is on android, it would display a material button, if on iOS, it would display a cupertino button

Answer (score 2):

Both flutter and react native has rich UI widget ready to be used in all moden apps. Some of them are part of the platform, others are available as third-party libraries developed by other programmers.

All though the two are not the same but because they all have rich UI it becomes very for one to predict their difference. But in terms of UI nativeness style out of the box below is how they differ:

The rendering engine of [Flutter](https://dartandflutter.com/reasons-why-you-should-choose-flutter-over-react-native/) controls each and every pixel it renders on the screen But react-native mainly relies on system calls. So based on this, I will assume the answer to your question is React-Reactive.